# external style sheet can not be find in the server part

Tags: css, webpack, server, styles, external

this is the project tree. As you see the CSS file is next to the file that is being called so I assumed the CSS file inside the HTML part of the server needs to be inserted externally as I did. However, this is not working. Anyone has any suggestion?
|-- project
     |-- .babelrc
     |-- package-lock.json
     |-- package.json
     |-- webpack.config.js
     |-- src
          |-- actions

```
      |-- components
      |   |-- entrypoints
      |   |   
      |   |-- pages
      |       
      |-- routes
      |    
      |-- index.js
      |--style.css
```

and this is my index.js:

```js
    import axios from "axios";
import "@babel/polyfill/noConflict";
import express from "express";
import proxy from "express-http-proxy";
// import compression from "compression";
import bodyparser from "body-parser";
import React from "react";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { renderRoutes, matchRoutes } from "react-router-config";
import reducers from "./client/reducers";
import Routes from "./client/Routes";
import serialize from "serialize-javascript";

// Server var
const app = express();

// View engine setup

// app.set("views",'src/views/pages');
// app.set("view engine", "ejs");
// console.log("views");

// Middleware
// app.use(compression());
app.use(
  "/api",
  proxy("http://react-ssr-api.herokuapp.com", {
    proxyReqOptDecorator(opts) {
      opts.headers["x-forwarded-host"] = "localhost:3000";
      return opts;
    },
  })
);
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
  const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://react-ssr-api.herokuapp.com",
    headers: { cookie: req.get("cookie") || "" },
  });
  const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    {},
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(axiosInstance))
  );
  // console.log(matchRoutes(Routes, req.path),">>>>>>>")
  const promises = matchRoutes(Routes, req.path).map(({ route }) => {
    return route.recipesData ? route.recipesData(store) : null;
  });
  // console.log(promises)

  Promise.all(promises).then((result) => {
    // console.log(result,"result")

    const home = renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter context={{}} location={req.path}>
          <div>{renderRoutes(Routes)}</div>
        </StaticRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
    res.send(`
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100;300;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"/>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    
      <title>server</title>
      <style>
      .header {
        font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
        background-color: violet;
        height:10vh;
        weight:100vw;
      }
      </style>
  </head>
  
    <body>
      <div id="root">${home}</div>
      <script>window.INITIAL_STATE=${serialize(store.getState())}</script>
      <script src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
  `);
  });

  // res.status(200).render("index",{
  //     reactApp:home,
  //     path:'/'
  // })
});

app.listen("3000", () => {
  console.log("connected to 3000");
});
```

but for some reason, style.css doesn't get attention. I am not sure where is the issue:

Comment: This must be because you have error in the upper part part of the code and because of that the execution of the codes stops there itself rather than going downwards try running just the `html` and `css` code

Comment: I fixed this by moving the style.css to the public folder outside of this which is the folder made through webpack on client-side